If I am to use midi keyboard only, do I still need audio interface?
I am thinking of purchasing 25 keys keyboard, but I am wondering if I need to also buy an audio interface to connect to a computer.
I will use no other instruments and no mics.

This question is similar to: Can you input a MIDI keyboard directly into a computer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Aaron Your linked question was asked 8 years ago. Now almost all keyboards come with a USB jack requiring no MIDI interface.

@JohnBelzaguy Then the answers to that question should be updated or a new one left.

@Aaron This question is not a duplicate. The old question is about connecting a specific keyboard that contains only a MIDI out. This question is about what  hardware may or may not be necessary when getting a new MIDI keyboard.

@JohnBelzaguy Actually, although the proposed dup is rather confusingly worded, it seems to suggest the fat OP actually has USB out from their keyboard as well. In which case Laurence’s answer seems the most reusable. (You have to figure no one is so dumb as to wonder whether they can plug 5-pin directly into a computer that doesn’t have that port… Right?)

@AndyBonner “fat OP”? No body shaming please…just kidding, I know you meant “fact”, lol. Being that the other question is old, ambiguous and had no clarification from the OP is reason enough to not make it the “go to” question for this topic IMO.

Actually, I realize as I re-read this that it never says the word "computer" anywhere. We're all assuming you want to get sound into a computer, but is that true? Are you just asking about how to hear audio? Many midi controllers don't have speakers or a headphone jack, just like how a computer keyboard doesn't have a screen to show what you type; they're just input devices. So yes, if you want to hear sound, depending on the model, you might need more devices.

@AndyBonner It may not say "computer", but the question is tagged daw.

You do not. Actually you probably won’t need anything but the keyboard controller itself. As long as you purchase a keyboard controller that has a USB connection that is compatible with your computer you will not need anything else. Older keyboard controllers had only MIDI jacks which required a MIDI interface to connect to the computer but pretty much all newer controllers have a USB connection.
If you get a controller keyboard then you will have to rely on your computer for generating sounds. I think you’re aware that this setup will not give you any audio capabilities other than the recording and playback of MIDI through the computer.

Pure MIDI keyboard controller does not have built-in sound, as opposed to a keyboard that has built-in sound plus MIDI capability.  The MIDI messages are transmitted either via a traditional MIDI port, or for newer MIDI controller there is a USB interface which is in essence a virtual MIDI port inside the USB driver of a compatible OS supported by the device.
I have used a 25 MIDI keyboard controller Nektar SE25 which I can connect either to a Mac, PC, iPhone or even an Android smartphone (with the right adapter, such as a USB A female to USB Type C male that doesn't corrupt the MIDI message).
But then you need a software to produce the sound, translating the MIDI message + the General MIDI instrument collection to regular sound wave through your device's built-in audio interface, where you can then plug in your headphones or your speakers.  There are a lot of free software out there, as well as iPhone/Android apps that can do the job.

It depends on if you get a midi enabled keyboard. If it is midi enabled you can plug it straight into your computer and it (should) work right out of the box. You may have to play around with some of the mappings but most of the time you dont. Now if you are getting a standard keyboard, it is NOT NESSARY to get an audio interface. HOWEVER, if is still possible and it will improve the sound. If you chose to not get an audio interface you can use a microphone to record the piano directly. If you are unhappy with how it sounds then you may want to look into audio interfaces as it would be going directly into your computer without the microphone. Also note that you dont need an external microphone, depending on your computer you may have one built in and you can also use a smartphone to record the audio, but just like the other things if you are unhappy with the sound from a phone you may want to look at an external microphone. Hope this helps!
Edit: If you don't already know you should look at the keyboard you are thinking of getting. Look to see if it is pure-midi which would only work plugged into a DAW or midi input on physical hardware (i.e. synthesizer)
Edit 2: Sorry should have read the title again before writing all of this but still I hope you may find this info useful!
TL:DR - No you can use a midi keyboard or a microphone, but audio interface will improve quality.
